# Fluid 960: Weird Alpha/Omega behavior

Tags: css, 960.gs, fluid-layout

I'm using Fluid 960 at the moment, and I'm getting some weird behavior with alpha/omega. My understanding of alpha/omega is that it's used to fix left/right margins in nested grids.

However, when I apply alpha/omega to a pair of nested grids, the left hand side grid has a really shallow indent while the right hand side grid has a large right-hand side indent (visual observations). Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: I see the same thing. Not sure either. Was getting confused myself! Anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its only needed for nested grids eg.

```
<div class="container_12">
    <div class="grid_2">sidebar</div>
    <div class="grid_6">
        <div class="grid_2 alpha">
            1
        </div>
        <div class="grid_2">
            2
        </div>
        <div class="grid_2 omega">
            3
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid_2">photo's</div>
    <div class="grid_2">advertisement</div>
</div>
```

Works as expected now.

Answer (score 2):

I think nested grids won't work in Fluid 960. Widths of grid are defined in term of percentage, instead of exact pixel.

Take previous answer as example, grid_6 will translate to 48% of width, then a grid_2 inside grid_6 will translate to 14.666% * 48%, but the expected of 14.466%.

I am also facing the same problem and may have to revert to non-fluid version. Please suggest if there is a solution or I am wrong.